# ListView Multiselect onCreateActionMode causing 2 Actionbars to appear

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar

I have an Android app in which I have a Main layout that has a Support Toolbar included as part of the layout using:

```
<include layout="@layout/toolbar"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android_layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

The toolbar that it includes is the following:

**layout/toolbar.xml**

```
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtViewHeading"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="@string/main_tab_status"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="28sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Then in my Main activity I inflate my toolbar_menu XML in the `onCreateOptionsMenu` method like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
    btnShare = menu.findItem(R.id.btnShare);
    btnSelectAll = menu.findItem(R.id.btnSelectAll);
    btnDelete = menu.findItem(R.id.btnDelete);
    return true;
}
```

However, when I try to use my `ListView` in `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL` mode, it also has an `onCreateActionMode` method. Thinking I would do what I did previously, I inflate the menu again using this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
     actionMode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu);
     return true;
}
```

However this causes another menu to appear above my main toolbar menu as seen in below screenshot.[image]

I don't want the second menu to appear, I want it to use the existing Toolbar that is in my Main layout. How can I accomplish this?

My Main.java (Main activity) is defined as an `AppCompatActivity`, where the Messages.java is a Fragment that is loaded into the Main activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a style with NoActionBar:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppThemeNoActonBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Use this style in AndroidManifest.xml in activity tag :

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppThemeNoActonBar" />
```

then add the toolbar to your activity layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="56dp" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar">

    <!--YOUR LAYOUT CODE-->

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then initialize java code for activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_third);
    Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add no action bar theme to your activity in manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
     android:theme="@style/YourThemeNoActionBar"/>
```

Comment: thank you, however I already have my Activity defined as @style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar.